# How to contain/resize the cropped camera image using react-native-gl-image-filters library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image-resizing

I'm using **react-native-gl-image-filters** library to apply different effects on the images directly captured from the device camera. The issue is when the image is crop, it is not maintaining the aspect ratio of the image, trying to fit within the given width and height hence the images are of low quality. I want the functionality similar to **resizeMode prop** on default react native image component. See the code below

```
              <Surface
                style={{
                  width: width / 1.1,
                  height: Dimensions.get("window").width / 1.1,
                }}
                ref={(ref) => {
                  image = ref;
                }}
              >
                <ImageFilters
                  width={width / 1.1}
                  height={width / 1.1}
                  {...filterState}
                >
                  {{
                    uri: imagePicker,
                  }}
                </ImageFilters>
              </Surface>
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gl-image-filters), there is no resizeMode prop. Can anyone tell me how to contain/resize the images from the camera on my own before passing the image to ****ImageFilter** Component.** So that image maintains its quality and aspect ratio.